# Water heater extra set of wires. Please help

Tags: plumbing

I'm installing a water heater when I opened the junction from the the house there was a black wire,  a white wire and a black and a white wire nutted together. What is the purpose of this and what should I do?[image]

Comment: Can you post a photo of the junction box please, including its innards?

Comment: Likely, the black & white already connected go to the heater on one side and an overheat control (thermal fuse or thermostat) on the other. Check the manufacturer's site for a schematic, if it wasn't included with the papers attached to the device.

Comment: The pic is the box from my house the two wires not connected  are from the new water heater.  I'm asking about the black and white wire that are connected together

Comment: How large a water heater is it?  Is it on a switch?  If so, that's a switch loop...  regardless, *this is a matter of idle curiosity. It goes without saying that you'll be leaving it alone.*

Comment: Can you post a photo that looks *down* into the box so that the back of the box is visible?

Comment: Did you ever get this working? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer that helped you the most, or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer

Answer (score 0):

It's fairly likely that the power comes first to the heater, and then has a "spur line" going to the switch or thermostat.  That "spur line" is wired as a **switch loop**, which by the way means you will not be using 240V smart switches.

**Leave the black-white nutted wires together**.  This is less important here, but vitally important on 120V switch loops.  Generally when doing swaps like this, take careful note (mark) which wires the old device was connected to, and don't disturb any wires except those.

The two capped-off wires are surely the ones that went to the old heater, and should go to the new heater.